# Efficiently scaling column of a sparse matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, out-of-memory, normalization, sparse-matrix

I have a sample X which is a sparse matrix (~5%) and now try to scale each column with a factor (basically tf-idf normalization).

Which I thought is a task easy to accomplish somehow now occurs to be not really supported. Here is what I used:

```
fac = log(size(X,1)./max(1,sum(X ~= 0)));
X = bsxfun(@times,X,fac); % this line gives an out of memory error
```

X is around 20,000x1,000,000 but only ~ 5% of the features are nonzero thus there shouldn't be any problem memorywise (the machine has 48 GB Ram and could easily handle a full matrix with the same number of elements allocated).

Actually I feel that there must be an easy way to do this, as it is a very common operation with sparse matrices holding data samples.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In terms of *could easily handle a full matrix with the same number of entries*: From my calculation a full matrix of that size would use 150GB of RAM.

Comment: not entries, i was referring to the actualy memory usage e.g. allocated number of elements

Comment: I don't get what you mean. A full `20,000-by-1,000,000` matrix would take up 150GB of memory.

Comment: @knedlsepp I meant that a sparse matrix only allocated the non-zero elements and thus a full matrix with the same number of **allocated** elements - not talking about the dimensionality - should fit in memory

Comment: Oh. Ok. So how did you solve the problem then? It seems to me my solution should work only if `bsxfun` also works.

Comment: I think there is no real solution without overhead, actually what I did to get it to work just change my experimental parameters to decrease the number of rows in X and also increase the sparsity.

If the memory overhead of the multiplication is the real problem - there seems to be no solution, as there are no inplace -operations(*=) supported in matlab - even with using a mexfile.

Comment: Actually the JIT compiler should optimize some operations to in-place operations: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/03/22/in-place-operations-on-data/

Comment: Oh nice one @knedlsepp, I did not know that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yey for linear algebra! Column scaling is right multiplication of diagonal matrix:

```
X = X*diag(sparse(fac));
```

Comment: @ArvidTerzibaschian: Hm. I was suspecting that `bsxfun` can't handle sparse matrices, but that's not the case (in my version of MATLAB). The above seems to have the same memory overhead as `bsxfun`. Are you sure your matrix is actually a `sparse`-matrix?

Comment: I just checked you are right, was blaming bsxfun too fast. The matrix is sparse but not 5% as expected.

Comment: @ArvidTerzibaschian: So how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use something along these lines:

1. Locate the nonzero values, and take note of the column index of each:
2. Divide each value by the entry of `fac` determined by the column, and put the results into `X`:

Code:

```
fac = log(size(X,1)./max(1,sum(X ~= 0)));   %// compute normalization vector
[~,  col, val] = find(X);                   %// step 1
X(X~=0) = val.*fac(col).';                 %'// step 2
```